# Can I keep the BOOTCAMP Partition on "secondary" drive when upgrading to SSD?

Tags: bootcamp, upgrade, ssd, migration

I have a Late 2008 MacBook Pro 2.53 GHz with 8 GB RAM and a 320 GB HDD. I'm running OS X Mountain Lion on the Macintosh HD (260 GB capacity, 100 GB used) and a Windows 7 on the 60 GB BOOTCAMP Partition.

What I want to do:

1. Install an SSD of 120 GB, move OS X there using Time Machine - don't see any problems here.
2. Keep the original 320 GB drive by moving it to the SuperDrive slot, erase the existing OS X system (since it will be migrated to the SSD)
3. Keep BootCamp unchanged on original (320 GB) drive.

Question: Will the BootCamp partition still work after moving the internal HDD? It will obviously not be on the boot drive anymore, since that should be the SSD.

If not, is there a way to make it work so I don't have to put it on the SSD? 
If not, are there tools for migration so I don't have to do a Windows image & reinstall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it shouldn't be a problem. Using the option key during booting should show all available installations to boot.